# Django average scores with through

Tags: django

Maybe this is a very newbie question, but I am stuck in this point. I do not know if the problem is the model or I do not understand very well aggregations and annotations.

I have a model like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    collection   = models.ManyToManyField(Book, through='BookCollection')

class Book(models.Model):
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class BookCollection(models.Model):
    user         = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book         = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    score        = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to get the score average for all the books and all users, excluding that ones that has a default score equals to 0 (this value represents that the user has the book in the collection, but it has not been rated). I am trying to use an annotation like this:

```
Book.objects.exclude(collection__score=0).annotate(avg=Avg('collection__score'))
```

but if there is a book rated with 0 and 3, for example, both entries are excluded.

Is there any way to tell Avg() that it should take into account only values greater than 0?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that in the Django ORM without raw SQL.

A better model would be to allow null values in your `score` field. Null values are ignored in `Avg()`:

```
class BookCollection(models.Model):
    ...
    score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

`None` is generally the best way to describe a lack of an entry in a field. This avoids confusion, e.g. in calculations such as calculating the average.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew that I could improve my model. It works!